# Are VNC servers too heavy to run on a raspberry pi?

Tags: hardware, display, vnc, cpu

I've read that VNC servers were made so that the powerful processor could control a compact display remotely.

A lot of things, including the raspberrypi.org documentation, include tutorials on application of a Virtual Network.

My question is: will a VNC be too heavy an application for a Pi (a 2B in my case)? Will it cause a lot of lag? If yes, how can one combat it?

If it makes a difference, I intend to use a VNC to connect my laptop hardware (screen, keyboard, etc.) to my raspberry pi.

Comment: I've used VNC to remotely access and control my Pi. It does put some strain on the Pi, but that depends on what model Pi you are using. As the early models had limited CPU power. The speed of your network connection will also determine how much lag there is. I've used a connection over Wi-Fi and apart from the odd stutter it works ok. A wired connection will of course be superior.

Comment: I used VNC for remote access to a 300MHz K6-II.  A Pi should have no trouble with it.

Answer (score 1):

I use a VNC server on my 3B, and the 3B and the 2B have similar specs. Also, [Raspbian Pixel](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/), the latest version of Raspbian, comes with a RealVNC Server installed. Back to the question: It should run fine. On a Pi 1 it probably wouldn't but using a Pi 2 you should be perfectly fine with running a VNC server

Answer (score 1):

I even run the VNC server on my Pi Zero Ws on a regular basis, albeit currently at 800x480 pixels only. I then connect from my laptop to the Pi Zero W's VNC server to do maintenance and development work on the "headless" Pi Zero W.